# Analytics Reporting API V4 api issue

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to implement Analytics Reporting API V4.
Using this example [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message ' in
>
> Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "invalid_scope", "error_description": "Empty or missing scope not allowed." }

Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well spotted.  I think there is an error in that tutorial.

```
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
```

Try and add the middle line above in your code.  You need to set a scope for it to work.

Let me know if it works and I will email the dev team and get the tutorial corrected.

Comment: Email sent I also logged it as an issue if you want to track it https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=993

Comment: The documentation has been update. Note: The purpose of these quickstart guides is to help you get through the initial hurdles of [API authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) with the Google API Client Libraries. As these libraries are under active development, these guides may occasionally fall out of sync with the latest client libraries. If you run into this issue you should check the[ Client Library's documentation](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) for the most uptodate information.